# Disable CRM form control through plugin / javascript based on specific Security Role

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have requirement to disable certain control's on the CRM form based on the user's role.
I am new to CRM & I am not fully sure how can I check user's role through javascript.
Requirement is that if user has certain roles I need to disable some controls on the form.

It would be nice if you can put code snippet. Thank you.

Exact scenario : Disable some control on CRM Account form through plugin/javascript based on some specific condition of other control (i.e When some picklist has some specific value I would like to disbale control and if user changes I would like to enable as well.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can get Current User's Security Roles as following

```
var roles = Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles();
```

Following code should work for you.

```
function OnLoad() {

    if (UserHasRole("Security Role Name")) {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("fieldname").setDisabled(true);
    } else {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("fieldname").setDisabled(false);
    }
}

function UserHasRole(roleName) {
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    var oDataEndpointUrl = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/";

    var org = Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName()
    var oDataEndpointUrl = "/" + org + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/";

    oDataEndpointUrl += "RoleSet?$top=1&$filter=Name eq '" + roleName + "'";

    var service = GetRequestObject();

    if (service != null) {
        service.open("GET", oDataEndpointUrl, false);
        service.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-Width", "XMLHttpRequest");
        service.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*");
        service.send(null);

        var requestResults = eval('(' + service.responseText + ')').d;

        if (requestResults != null && requestResults.results.length == 1) {
            var role = requestResults.results[0];

            var id = role.RoleId;

            var currentUserRoles = Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles();

            for (var i = 0; i < currentUserRoles.length; i++) {
                var userRole = currentUserRoles[i];
                if (GuidsAreEqual(userRole, id)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function GetRequestObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    } 
    else {
        try 
        {
            return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        } catch (ex) {
           return null;
        }
    }
}

function GuidsAreEqual(guid1, guid2) {
    var isEqual = false;

    if (guid1 == null || guid2 == null) {
        isEqual = false;
    } else {
        isEqual = guid1.replace(/[{}]/g, "").toLowerCase() == guid2.replace(/[{}]/g, "").toLowerCase();
    }

    return isEqual;
}
```

Apart from that, have a look at field level security feature in Dynamics CRM. Check the link below:

[How to configure Field Level Security in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamics101trainingcentercrm/archive/2013/09/03/how-to-configure-field-level-security-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx)

Comment: I have not even looked at your link. I have took the code from this link: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a7f7cd4-0a62-4053-801b-54605cc1c98b/showhide-section-based-on-a-security-role-in-dynamics-crm-2011-online?forum=crm

Comment: @AndriiButenko Just opened your link after you complained. If you still think I have copied from your link, I am happy to delete my answer. But I believe that my answer is more appropriate than your's as its not redirecting to external site and it provides the complete solution rather than just giving an idea.

Comment: You are free to do whatever you want.